# Symfony2 refactoring issues, services, configuration, container?

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection, containers

I have been refactoring code to **learn** about services, DI, etc.

This is part of my **Controller**

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $weatherConfig = array(
        'city'  => 'Detroit',
        'lang'  => 'en',
        'units' => 'metric'
    );

    $weather = new WeatherService($this->get('_weather_finder'), $weatherConfig);

    return $this->render('WeaTherBundle:Weather:index.html.twig',
        array(
            'weather' => $weather->getWeather()
        ));
}
```

Now I'd like to make this code thinner, but after trying different formulas I haven't been able to:

1.- put the configuration parameters **$weatherConfig** in a: `container`? (is this a good solution?)

2.- Make the **render** line thinner

3.- Are these good ideas thinking that maybe I'd like to add more cities (configuration settings) in the future. Suggestions?

Cheers.-

Comment: I'd make `$weatherConfig` an argument to weather service's `getWeather` method. Also, why are you wrapping a service from the container into `new WeatherService()`? It'd be a lot cleaner if you let the `_weather_finder` be the topmost service you call `getWeather` on.

Comment: A container is available to your controller as it extends `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`. This class implements `ContainerAware`, and the container gets injected into `$this->container`, `$this->get()` is just a wrapper to `$this->container->get()` here.

Comment: On changing the `render` line, well, there's pretty much nothing you can do about it, but maybe `@Template` annotation could simplify things a bit: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html

Comment: And the third question is more on architecture than on the framework. I'd suggest passing configuration (note that's basically not a configuration, but a criteria) as an argument to `getWeather()` method, possibly wrapping it into a class.

Comment: Thanks, still have have some doubts. Actually `$weatherConfig` is passed to `getWeather` but inside `WeatherService` which `implements WeatherInterface`. I think that maybe is a good idea to pass the parameters to the constructor and then work with them in the implementation of `getWeather` in case I want to use a different external weather API. This is the meat of my question: How can I put `$weatherConfig` in a **config file**? and then instead of calling **new** create `WeatherService` in the `service.yml` file???

Answer (score 1):

Overall, the code is ok but I can give some advices:

- You should not use a `_` to identify your own services. Instead, prefix it with your bundle id: `wea_ther` (this is Symfony2's recommandation).
- I cannot understand what is the role of your service reading is name `_weather_service`. I would prefer something like `wea_ther.weather_forecaster`. Same remark for the class location and name.
- A possible improvement would be to put the parameter `geo.location` in the [configuration of your bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html). At least prefix it with your bundle id.

Here is the corresponding code:

```
parameters:
    wea_ther.weather_finder.class: Cmfcmf\OpenWeatherMap
    wea_ther.weather_forecaster.class: Wea\TherBundle\Weather\Forecaster
    wea_ther.geo_location:
        city: Santiago de Chile
        lang: en
        units: metric

services:
    wea_ther.weather_finder:
        class: "%wea_ther.weather_finder.class%"

    wea_ther.weather_forecaster:
        class: '%wea_ther.weather_forecaster.class%'
        arguments: [@wea_ther.weather_finder, %wea_ther.geo_location%]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue this way, I'd appreciate if someone can tell me about the *correctness* of the code. I still need to meditate on what I did :P

**Controller**:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $weather = $this->get('_weather_service');

    return $this->render('WeaTherBundle:Weather:index.html.twig',
        array(
            'weather' => $weather->getWeather()
        ));
}
```

**services.yml**:

```
parameters:
    _weather_finder.class: Cmfcmf\OpenWeatherMap
    _weather_service.class: Wea\TherBundle\Services\WeatherService
    geo.location:
        city: Santiago de Chile
        lang: en
        units: metric

services:
    _weather_finder:
        class: "%_weather_finder.class%"

    _weather_service:
        class: '%_weather_service.class%'
        arguments: [@_weather_finder, %geo.location%]
```